# emmeans Can't handle an object of class “bigglm” in R

Tags: r, class, bigdata, glm, emmeans

I'm using "bigglm" function in R and I also would like to use the "emmeans" function to make post-hoc analyzes and ploting. However the function emmeans Can't handle an object of class “bigglm”.

**There is a way to construct an object of class "glm" from class "bigglm"?**

Here is an example

```
library(biglm)
library(emmeans)
data(trees)
trees$f <- factor(rep(c("A","B"),length.out = nrow(trees)))
ff <-log(Volume)~f

a <- glm(ff,data=trees)
summary(a)
emmeans(a,~f)

b <- bigglm(ff,data=trees, chunksize=10)
summary(b)
emmeans(b,~f)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the `emmobj()` function may be used to construct what you need, if you can obtain the info needed (coefs, covariances, etc.)

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Be careful with the `linfct` argument - that’s the hardest one to get right because it has the represent the contrast coding for each node in the reference grid.

Comment: Yes, I got stuck in this argument because I didn't manage to extract (or deduce) the linear combination of bhat for each combination of levels. Also, I do not know what to do if I have a continuous predictor variable.

Comment: Maybe fit exactly the same model to a subset of the data, using `lm()`, then get `emmeans(...)@linfct`. But your subset has to include all of the factor combinations.

Comment: Please see my answer for one workaround. Another is the `qdrg()` function (quick and dirty reference grid) that I just added to the package. It is available from github -- https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that "biglm" and "bigglm" objects are very similar to "lm" and "glm" objects, with only minor changes to their structure. So it appears that all we have to do is to trick `emmeans` into thinking it is one of those. Here is a utility for that purpose:

```
as.glm = function(mod) {
    mod$coefficients = coef(mod)
    mod$df.residual = mod$df.resid
    class(mod) = c(class(mod), "glm", "lm")
    mod
}
```

Now we get:

```
> emmeans(as.glm(b), "f")
 f   emmean        SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A 3.288124 0.1337527 Inf  3.025974  3.550275
 B 3.256313 0.1381392 Inf  2.985565  3.527061

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: do you know how to do the same for vglm objects to trick them into glm/lm?

Comment: Look at the help page for `qdrg`. You may be able to get it that way.

Comment: Hmm couldn't get it. I wonder if there is a way to act emmeans on a data frame or tibble. I found a way to extract my terms, SE, coefficients and p vals from my vglm model object but can't pass it to emmeans. Is there a way to now convert the tibble back to a glm objec,t or a way for emmeans to act on these extracted data?

Comment: there is no way to run emmeans on a tibble or a data frame. It needs a *model*.